# is it possible to trigger c++ code, initiated by html events in minko?

Tags: html, c++, overlay, minko

Using [minko](http://minko.io), "html overlay" feature, is it possible to send events to c++ code from html?

The example provided, with the framework clearly demonstrate how to send events from c++ towards html (by incrementing a counter and having it reflect in html), is it possible to have the communication the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

HTML DOM events are wrapped and made available as C++ signals. So you can do something like:

```
dom->getElementById("my-element-id")->onclick()->connect(
  [](dom::AbstractDOMMouseEvent::Ptr event)
  {
    // do something...
  }
);
```

It's actually done in the same example: https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/example/html-overlay/src/Main.cpp#L110

You can also send and receive "messages" both ways using the `AbstractDOM::sendMessage()` method in C++ or `Minko.sendMessage()` function in JS. You can listen to those messages using `AbstractDOM::onmessage()` in C++ and `Minko.addEventListener("message", yourCallbackFunction)`.

Note that you can also call `AbstractDOM::eval()` in your C++ code to execute JavaScript code. It's how we've implemented most of the things actually.

Comment: ok, seems to be working now, as I can get the click coord, in c++, however I have 2 questions :
1-clientX(), pageX(), screenX() seems to be returning same values .. is this expected ? (compiling as linux64)
2-how can i read back the parameter passed from JS in c++ ?
I am sending this :  
`...onclick="Minko.sendMessage('first.test')"...`  I want to read back 'first.test' in c++.

Comment: I've edited my original answer.

IDK about the clientX / pageX things: web browsers give me a headache everytime I read the docs about those values. But AFAIK it's to be expected indeed.

Comment: Your updated answer was what I was looking for, and it worked perfectly for my case. Many thanks !

As for clientX, pageX thing, it is not a big issue for me now, but will update you in case I find a weird behaviour in some browser.